# How to search for 8-bit value in a memory area and output the memory address? SBC86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, nasm, memory-address

I have to create a program for university that searches for a previously specified 8-bit value in the memory area C000H-CFFFH (monitor program of the SBC86). We use an i8086 emulator.

But I have absolutely no idea how exactly I search the memory area and output the memory address of the value found.

Comment: Do you mean **segment** C000h to CFFFh or linear address?

Comment: Load the byte from C000, see if it is the value you're looking for, and if not, then load the byte from C001, and see if that is the byte you're looking for, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REPNE SCASB` to search for the known value. We'll assume that value is currently in `AL` (if it's not, `mov` it there first.)

`REPNE SCASB` (repeat if not equal, scan string byte) works like this:

1. Compare `AL` to `byte ptr [es:di]` (the byte at the memory address specified by `di`) and set the flags accordingly.
2. Add 1 to `di` (if direction flag is clear, otherwise subtract 1) and subtract 1 from `cx`, without altering the flags.
3. If `AL = byte ptr [es:di]`, OR `cx = 0`, move to the next instruction.
4. Otherwise, goto 1.

```
cld            ;we want scasb to auto-inc
mov di,0C000h  ;begin search at $C000 (assumes ES = segment you want to search)
mov cx,1000h   ;repeat until $CFFF
repne scasb    ;begin the search
```

At this point, `di` will point to the memory address after the byte of interest, if it was found. However, in this case you still need a conditional branch, for the corner case where the desired byte was at the last possible position. Looking at `di` alone won't tell you that.

```
cld
mov di,0C000h  
mov cx,1000h   
repne scasb    
jne notFound 
    ;your code for what happens when you find it goes here
    jmp done
notFound:
    ;your code for what happens when you don't find it goes here
done:
ret
```

EDIT: Changed the incorrect usage of `ds:si` to `es:di` in accordance with [the hardware specifications.](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd)

EDIT 2: Corrected mistake, now says `es:di` points to byte AFTER the match.

Comment: `scasb` uses `es:di`, not `(ds:)si`. Besides, on a match flags will be ZR (zero flag set) and `byte [es:di - 1]` will have the match. You can continue searching afterwards for additional matches.

Comment: I could have sworn it was `ds:si`. Oh well, I'll fix it.

Comment: Your code still doesn't set ES=0 to make linear address = offset.

Comment: I didn't want to assume what `es` was in this case. I don't know what memory model is being used for the program. The programmer can set that up themself (I didn't set `al` either for the same reason)

Comment: This is still wrong: "At this point, di will contain the address of the byte, if it was found." The pointer in `es:di` will actually point one element behind the match, which means one byte in case of `scasb`